# Seurat data visualization

Tags: seurat

Hi I am using public data pbmc to practice single cell analysis
I got stuck at this point with this error message.
Just started with R and having a hard time
Could anyone give a pointer?
Many thanks

## Ridge plots - from ggridges. Visualize single cell expression distributions in each cluster

Code: RidgePlot(pbmc3k.final, features = features, ncol = 2)

Error in FetchData.Seurat(object = object, vars = features, slot = slot) :
object 'features' not found

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define what 'features' you want to see.

so :

```
features = c('Sox2', 'Sox9') #etc, as an example
```

or, you can add them as a variable which you call features :

```
features <- c('Sox2', 'Sox9') 

RidgePlot(pbmc3k.final, features = features, ncol = 2)
#if they are mouse genes, human genes are all caps.
```

Comment: sorry for a late reply, but thanks!

Comment: If this has solved your question please upvote it.